# How to set the date format of dd-MMM-yy in DataGridView at design time in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am developing the vb.net windows application.

I have used the grid view for displaying data.

I want to use the `dd-MMM-yy` format in `DataGridView`.

for example, I want to display the time as 01-Jan-16

but I cant see the this format in VS 2012 IDE .

here is the image of it...

[image]

can I use the custom format for it ? What is the format for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataGridViewCellStyle.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format(v=vs.110).aspx) property at design-time or run-time to set format to `dd-MMM-yy`. Then it shows date as `06-Jan-16`.

Go to `Columns` property, and open `Edit Columns` window. Under the `Appearance` category, edit `DefaultCellStyle`, open `CellmStyle Builder` window and under `Behavior` category enter the custom `Format`.

Also you can click on `...` and open `Format String Dialog` and choose between predefined formats and custom format and enter custom format there:

Or using code you can write this code:

```
Dim DataGridViewCellStyle1 = New DataGridViewCellStyle()
DataGridViewCellStyle1.Format = "dd-MMM-yy"
Me.Column1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1
```

For more information about suppported formatting that you can use with [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format(v=vs.110).aspx) property, see [Formatting Types in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=vs.110).aspx).