# DataGridView - how to set the currency format for a single column ONLY

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, t-sql, datagridview

I am trying to use the datagridview for a basket. I have got it to display the basket of the customer but I would like it to display the currency for the Price column, but i have a Quantity column as well, so if I put the default style as currency then it will change both columns to the currency format.

What I want to be able to do is add the currency format to the Price Column but not to the quantity column.

Here is the code that displays the basket (Form_load)

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dataadapter =
          new SqlDataAdapter(
              "select p.productname 'Product Name', b.productquantity 'Quantity', c.categoryname 'Category', p.price 'Current Price' " +
              "from basket b join products p on b.productid = p.productid " +
              "join Categories c on c.categoryid = p.categoryid " +
              $"where b.customerid = {CustomerId}", con);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            dataadapter.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
```

The CustomerId is collected from a txt file that stores the CustomerId when they log in.

If there is any more code that you would like to see then comment and i will add it.

This is what i get on the form with the currency added as the style.
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set format of data of a column using `Format` property of its `DefaultCellStyle` property of the column.

For example to use currency format for second column of a `DataGridView` using current culture, you can use such code:

```
grid1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

Or for example to use an specific culture and specific decimal numbers:

```
grid1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2";
grid1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
```

**More Information**

- [How to: Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-format-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Standard Numeric Format Strings - The Currency ("C") Format Specifier.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

**Note**

If you are using an object data source, then you can use the following approaches as well. The Foundation is same, setting suitable format for the column, but using attributes:

- [DataAnnotations attributes for DataGridView in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885956/3110834)
- [Using custom attributes to control appearance of DataGridView columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50911813/3110834)

Answer (score 1):

Create DataGridView columns at design time and sets the price only format the Current Price column
[Datagridview tutorial](http://checktechno.blogspot.com.es/2013/09/datagridview-tutorial.html)

[Set DateTime format in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638518/how-to-set-the-date-format-of-dd-mmm-yy-in-datagridview-at-design-time-in-vb-net) This link is seen as setting the date format, just change the date format for the currency format.

Comment: How may i got about do that, as i haven't done so before?