# How to set unbound datagridview column cell to currency in c#

Tags: c#

i had this unbound datagridview that add columns during form load;

here is the code;

```
private void loadfields()
        {
            dgvbulkentries.ColumnCount = 15;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[0].Name = "ID No";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[0].Width = 80;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[1].Name = "Surname";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[1].Width = 150;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[2].Name = "First Name";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[2].Width = 150;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[3].Name = "Name Extn";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[3].Width = 40;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[4].Name = "Middle Name";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[4].Width = 150;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[5].Name = "Course";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[5].Width = 110;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[6].Name = "Year";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[6].Width = 40;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[6].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[7].Name = "Street/Block";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[7].Width = 150;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[8].Name = "Subdivision";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[8].Width = 150;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[9].Name = "Barangay";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[9].Width = 150;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[10].Name = "Municipality/City";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[10].Width = 150;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[11].Name = "Province";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[11].Width = 150;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[12].Name = "GWA";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[12].Width = 60;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[12].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[13].Name = "Units";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[13].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[13].Width = 50;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[14].Name = "Total School Fees";
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[14].Width = 100;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn sexes = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            sexes.HeaderText = "Sex";
            sexes.Name = "Sex";
            sexes.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
            sexes.Items.Add("Male");
            sexes.Items.Add("Female");
            dgvbulkentries.Columns.Add(sexes);
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[15].DisplayIndex = 5;
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[15].Width = 80;
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ssfapremarks = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            ssfapremarks.HeaderText = "Remarks";
            ssfapremarks.Name = "Remarks";
            ssfapremarks.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
            ssfapremarks.Items.Add("Enrolled");
            ssfapremarks.Items.Add("Not Enrolled");
            dgvbulkentries.Columns.Add(ssfapremarks);
            dgvbulkentries.Columns[16].Width = 120;
        }
```

I already set the code for currency textbox for a specific column in a datagridview. But the problem is, when i enter numbers in a cell, it does not change at all.

This is the code i included;

```
private void dgvbulkentries_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dgvbulkentries.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n";
    }
```

**For example**, when i enter numbers to a specific column in the datagridview, it does not format the value as currency format. i already did what you had suggested but its not working

what did i miss?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView - how to set the currency format for a single column ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026196/datagridview-how-to-set-the-currency-format-for-a-single-column-only)

Comment: Looking at the code you missed the correct curreny format, ie 'c' or 'c2'. Why would you ever change it during editing??

Comment: @TaW will my answer solve OP's requirement?

Comment: You use a valid format; but I don't really know the requirement. Setting the format could and should be done once and for all when creating the fields, imo, not in some Cellxxx events. The currency should work from the start, ie directly after loading.

Comment: I tried that but it seems that OP is entering the values in DGV at the runtime(like text box column) when i tried changing format while initializing it didnt in my system  but after using cell leave it woked as per request

Comment: Did the answer solve ur issue ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026196/datagridview-how-to-set-the-currency-format-for-a-single-column-only) answer 
After knowing the issue I think using CellLeave event of data grid view will solve ur issue

```
void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   dgvbulkentries.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2";
   dgvbulkentries.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
   dgvbulkentries.Columns[14].ValueType = typeof(decimal);
}
```

Comment: Nothings happens.. what did i miss..?

Comment: You should try this when you are Initializing the DataGrid View

Comment: I already tried with form load but nothing happens. Can you give me a little hint on how to do this?

Comment: can you tell what happens when you do that doest it format value?

Comment: For example, when i enter numbers to a specific column in the datagridview, it does not format the value as currency format. i already did what you had suggested but its not working. please help..

Comment: Ok now I understood what is ur problem give me some time i'll edit answer once i have found a solution