# Set Format of auto-generated columns in DataGridView having object DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-2.0

I would like to auto create all the columns for my `DataGridView` based on my custom class. Every thing works like it should, but what I need is to format and align the cell values.

So is there an attribute that I can add to my field (HeightMeter) so that it can align and format as required. To do this in a manual column create code, You will use the following:

```
DataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
DataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

How to I specify the DefaultCellStyle properties when using the AutoGenerateColumns solution - Note I am limited to using .net 2 :(

Here is a sample of what I need and what I get:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
  private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
  private DataGridView dataGridView2 = new DataGridView();
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

    dataGridView2.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    dataGridView2.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

    Controls.Add(dataGridView2);
    Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

    Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    Text = "";
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    PopulateLists();
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = people;

    CreateAndPopulateGrid2();
  }

  public void CreateAndPopulateGrid2()
  {
    DataGridViewColumn columnName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    columnName.HeaderText = "Name";

    DataGridViewColumn columnHeight = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    columnHeight.HeaderText = "Height [m]";
    columnHeight.ValueType = typeof(double);

    columnHeight.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    columnHeight.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
    dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
    dataGridView2.Columns.Clear();
    dataGridView2.Columns.Add(columnName);
    dataGridView2.Columns.Add(columnHeight);

    DataGridViewRow row;
    foreach (Person p in people)
    {
      row = new DataGridViewRow();
      row.CreateCells(dataGridView2);
      row.Cells[0].Value = p.Name;
      row.Cells[1].Value = p.HeightMeter;
      dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
    }
  }

  private void PopulateLists()
  {
    people.Clear();
    people.Add(new Person("Harry", 1.7523));
    people.Add(new Person("Sally", 1.658));
    people.Add(new Person("Roy", 2.158));
    people.Add(new Person("Pris", 1.2584));
  }
}

class Person
{
  [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Height [m]")]
  public double HeightMeter { get; set; }

  public Person(string name, double heightMeter)
  {
    Name = name;
    HeightMeter = heightMeter;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to generate my DataGridView columns from a class. What i need is to apply formatting on certain columns. This can be done when manually creating columns with the DefaultCellStyle property. But i need to define this like I define the name of the column with an attribute or any way that does not force me to create each column by hand.

Comment: You can create some custom attributes and decorate properties with those attributes, wherever you are setting up the grid, after auto-generating columns, you can write some code to extract metadata from those attributes and apply on grid.

Comment: As another option, you can let the datagridview auto-generate columns. Then write some code to manually setup columns. For example `dgv.Columns["Id"].Width = 200;` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, This is definintly an option, but is there a built in way so i dont have to create my own attribute? Like using [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Name")] sets the HeaderText of the column, Is there no way to access the DefaultCellStyle in the same way(bult in)? If there is no way that any one knows of, I will create my own attribute to access that properties.

Comment: There is no built-in way.

Comment: That sucks, plan B then. Create my own attribute... I like your other option, but the class I am using contains multiple fields that require formatting so to do the following (works 100%) "dataGridView1.Columns["HeightMeter"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
      dataGridView1.Columns["HeightMeter"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";" for each field is a bit much. Would of loved it if there were a built in function. Thanks for the assist. :)

Comment: I think you will like these posts: [DataAnnotations attributes for DataGridView in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885956/3110834) and [DataAnnotations Validation attributes for Windows Forms](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/dataannotations-validation-attributes-in-windows-forms/).

Comment: If you can upgrade .NET version ;) Otherwise you can implement the attributes yourself and use the approach described in the linked posts.

Comment: I wish I could. 10 years of code to check when upgrading to latest .NET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Using custom attributes to control appearance of DataGridView columns

When auto-generating columns in `DataGridView`, there is built-in support for a few attributes including `ReadOnly`, `DisplayName` and `Browsable` attribute. For example, if you mark a property using `Browsable(false)` it will not be added as a column to `DataGridView`.

But for `Format`, there is no such built-in support. You can create a custom `DisplayFormat` attribute and write some code to use it in `DataGridView` after auto generating columns.

For example, let's say you have a class like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
public class Product
{
    [DisplayName("Code")]
    [Description("Unique code of the product")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Product Name")]
    [Description("Name of the product")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Unit Price")]
    [Description("Unit price of the product")]
    [DisplayFormat("C2")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

And as a result, we are going to have a `DataGridView` like the screenshot, which can see we used the value of `Description` attribute as tooltip text for columns and also we used `DisplayFormat` to show the price in currency format:

[image]

First we should create the custom attribute for format, `DisplayFormat`:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
public class DisplayFormatAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DisplayFormatAttribute(string format)
    {
        Format = format;
    }
    public string Format { get; set; }
}
```

Then load data and auto generate columns, for example:

```
var list = new List<Product>() {
    new Product(){ Id=1, Name="Product 1", Price= 321.1234},
    new Product(){ Id=2, Name="Product 2", Price= 987.5678},
};
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

Then to take advantage of attributes, you can write such code which is not dependent to the model type:

```
var type = ListBindingHelper.GetListItemType(dataGridView1.DataSource);
var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type);
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    var p = properties[column.DataPropertyName];
    if (p != null)
    {
        var format = (DisplayFormatAttribute)p.Attributes[typeof(DisplayFormatAttribute)];
        column.ToolTipText = p.Description;
        column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = format == null ? null : format.Format;
    }
}
```

You can simply encapsulate above code in a method like `void SetupColumn(DataGridView dgv)` or if you have a derived `DataGridView`, you can create a `DataBind(object data)` method and in the method, assign `data` to `DataSource` and then use above code as rest of body of the method.

**Note**

I also read in the comments under your question that you have told '*...for each field is a bit much.*' If for any reason you don't like the attribute approach, you can simply stick to a for loop like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    if (c.ValueType == typeof(double))
    {
        c.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";
        c.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    }
}
```

## DataAnnotations attributes for in Windows Forms

To see how can you use data annotations attribute in Windows Forms for DataGridView and also for Validation, take a look at these posts:

- [DataAnnotations attributes for DataGridView in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885956/3110834)
- [DataAnnotations Validation attributes for Windows Forms](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/dataannotations-validation-attributes-in-windows-forms/)

Comment: Make sure read the edited version of the answer. I change the code to .NET 2. The first version of the code was written i higher versions of the .NET.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like the attribute approach yes. This will work greate because not all of my double fields will have the same format. For some fields I will need more decimal points then for others. Will Implement above solution. Thank you very much.