# How do I get a Grid Control column in C# to display a price with two decimal places?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a column in the grid control of C# to display prices with two decimal points. I have to do this in two places: one is for US dollars, and one is for various European currencies, and have ended up using different methods for each, but both have the same issues. The issue is that if a price is blank, the column will only display the currency symbol. If it's a round number (no decimals), it shows the price and the dollar sign, but no decimals. If the price has change that is a factor of 10 (ten cents, twenty cents, etc), it only shows the first decimal spot. The only time it shows the correct format is when it has a decimal that doesn't have a zero for the second number (like 35 cents). Examples are below:

If no price being called, it just shows **$** instead of $0.00

If the price is 123 it shows $123 instead of **$123.00**

If the price is 123.30 it shows $123.3 instead of **$123.30**

If the price is 123.35 it shows $123.35, which is the format I want it in.

For the US dollars, I have it formatting the number under the DisplayFormat Property in the Properties window where it formats as **Numeric "$#.##"**.

For the European currencies, I have it formatting it in the query that calls the numbers from the database. For example, if the currency is the euro, then it formats the price using this part of the SQL code from the query's CASE statement:

```
WHEN Currency_Type = 'EURO' THEN (CAST('€' AS varchar(2)) + CAST(Price AS varchar(9)))
```

Outside of the queries that get the prices (which is SQL), I'm using C# to program the rest of the program.

Does anyone know how to get one or both to display showing the currency symbol AND the price to two decimal places?

**UPDATE**: replacing the # with 0 in the US currency fixed the issue. Still trying to get the European side working. It is a bit harder since it uses multiple currency types (the euro, the pound, etc), which was why I was using the query to alter the currency symbols.

Comment: See the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026196/datagridview-how-to-set-the-currency-format-for-a-single-column-only - And if you need more information on specific currency formats: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman With the stackoverflow link, it looks like the currency already comes in the correct format. As for the other link, followed it to the custom numeric format, and replacing the # with 0 worked for the US currency, but not with the European currencies